# Nivo Slider URL doesn't change with the image

Tags: javascript, jsp, url, nivo-slider

I'm trying to have a different url on each of my image in my Nivo slider but it seems to only load the image when it slides meaning the url doesn't change, this is present in all browsers.

My code in my jsp tag is:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper2">
   <div id="slider-home-banners" class="nivoSlider">
       <a href="/loans.html"><img src="/images/assets/loans.png" height="120" width="231" alt="" /></a>
       <a href="/login.html" onclick="google event tracking"><img src="/images/assets/new-site-asset.png" height="120" width="231" alt="" /></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have the standard css and js files from http://dev7studios.com/plugins/nivo-slider/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I was running an old version of Nivo Slider. Once I updated to the latest version the issue went away, you can download this from http://dev7studios.com/downloads/63.
Nivo also says it requires jQuery 1.7 but I am running jQuery 1.6.2. and it seems to be ok.

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was removing the slider shadow class in my default .css , might be somewhere else for you it looks like this

```
.slider-wrapper #slider-shadow{
    position:absolute;
    left:0%;
    top:0%;
    background:url(../images/slider-shadow.png);
    width:993px;
    height:324px;
    z-index:100;
}
```

once i took this away it all worked fine.
hope this helps someone.